# stack statically link external library on mac

Tags: haskell, zeromq, haskell-stack

I would really like to create a single binary for my application however it depends on libzmq and I am building on OSX, has anyone managed to get an external library linking correctly on a mac?

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar with lua. My aproach is to pass full path to the static library to ghc. In cabal file:

```
if os(darwin)
  ghc-options: /usr/local/lib/liblua5.1.a
```

According to [documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using.html#meaningful-file-suffixes) ghc will pass it to linker:

> Files with other suffixes (or without suffixes) are passed straight to
>   the linker.

However it doesn't work if the library is used in other package which you depend on. So if you are using e.g. `zeromq4-haskell` package, then you need to modify it locally.